# Is it good practice to use HTML rather than Swing components to create forms in a Java desktop application?

Tags: java, html, forms, swing

[*Thanks for pointing out that Swing cannot be used in Android; I've edited my question accordingly.*]

In my desktop application (intended mostly for PCs with MS Windows, but with the prospect of making it available for other platforms and devices), I'd like to create a component that would display customizable forms which would consist of variously formatted text and input (text)fields. For example, there would be a set of ten exam questions, each numbered and represented by a sentence with certain missing parts (words, phrases) the user would be asked to complete by filling in with whatever they think might be the correct answer. Their imput would then be evaluated upon clicking on the submit button. For example ("[.......]" represents a text field):

> 1. While the **trout** is a [........], the **cat** is a [........].
> 2. Most **deciduous** trees have [........] whereas **conifers** have [........]
> 3. The **horse** and the **donkey** are both [........].

...and so on. After the user submits their answers, my code would check if what they'd filled in was "fish", "mammal", "leaves", "needles" or "equids", respectively, etc.

Now, my first idea was to use a combination of **JLabels** (with or without HTML formatting) and **JTextFields**, the former displaying the text and the latter displaying the textfields, of course, so the input string for the first question, for instance, would consist of 3 JLabels and 2 JTextFields (JLabel + JTextField + JLabel + JTextField + JLabel), etc. They would all be on a **JPanel**, arranged by means of a (combination of) **Layout Manager**(s).

Then an idea crossed my mind: *What if I created the whole form in **HTML** instead?* Judging from [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145405/display-and-interact-with-an-html-form-in-a-swing-application) it is possible. However, would that be ***good*** or **bad** practice? Would there be any serious performance issues (cf. [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116091/html-tag-in-java-swing-components) and [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779818/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-html-styling-in-java-swing-elements)), for example, any drawbacks or disadvantages, especially with regard to what I'd like to make? It feels a bit dirty.

Sorry if this is a silly question to you, but since I'm relatively *new* to both Java and Swing and lack any experience, any warnings, comments, directions and pieces of advice will be welcome and greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Android does not support Swing.

Comment: Ah, good to know! I'll edit my question accordingly. Thank you! I'm absolutely new to Android as I only acquired my first Android phone a couple of months ago.

Comment: Android doesn't support swing. You can design all those components via xml

Comment: Wonderful, thank you @VivekMishra. At least I know now what to focus on. I'll dig for some information on that to avoid bothering anyone with any other potentially silly questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Andoroid doesn't support Swings. For web Swings/Applets needs Java Plug-in and most of the browsers stopped sup[porting Java Plugin. And Java is going to remove the Applet support in near future.

If you want your application to work with both mobile and web (Desktop browser) then go for HTML5, CSS and follow Responsive UI guidelines. There are frameworks like Phonegap, CodeNameone .. etc available to help the same code work in Mobile as well. (Hybrid app development).

Comment: In fact, I intended to create an offline application rather than a web-based one. One that would require the user to have installed the JRE on their PC (MS Windows, for instance), but the idea of making it available for Android mobile phones is attractive, indeed.